# What if I don't want to sudo apt-get upgrade everything? What is best practice?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a general question regarding upgrading. For example, my situation is that I installed a newer version of Passenger and apparently in order to use the new version correctly I need to recompile nginx. The instructions on the documentation officially recommends these commands.

> If Passenger was installed through the Phusion Passenger APT repository, then you can upgrade Passenger along with Nginx through APT using the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> ```

Won't this upgrade EVERYTHING on my server. What if I upgrade a package and it doesn't work with something else. Can't I just upgrade nginx and passenger only. What would best practice be in this situation? I ask because I've done something like this which created a nightmare for me simply by upgrading everything and I really don't want to repeat that error.

Comment: Upgrading everything regularily is good practice. If you don't do that you can end up with a bunch of unpatched libraries with known security exploits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normally good practice to upgrade everything (security etc, and package conflicts should normally be reported by `apt`). However as you say, there are cases where things can break regardless.

You can upgrade a single package with:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade <package>
```

From the `man` page:

> --only-upgrade
>
> Do not install new packages; when used in conjunction with install     only-upgrade will install upgrades for already installed packages only and ignore requests to install new packages.

In terms of best practice... if you're running a serious server, ideally you should devote time to incrementally upgrading each package and ensuring it works with all your other packages, on a non-production test server. That way any conflicts can be identified and workarounds found.